# Migrating to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration

I'm 18 years old and live in the U.S. but my visa expired 2 years ago. I've been abandoned by my mother (here in the US), and I don't know what to do. My father lives in England, although I don't know him well. I guess I'd be able to go live with him, so I can at least go to school and work and keep out of his way.

My nationality is Commonwealth of Dominica (not Dominican Republic), so I don't need a visa to enter the UK. Other than that, will there be issues in going to live there?

Comment: Are you under 18?

Comment: I'm 18 currently.

Comment: I ran Dominica nationality through [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). It looks as though you would not need a visa if you intended a short vacation in the UK. You would need a visa to live long term in the UK.

Comment: I suggest adding your age to the question. Comments can get deleted. It does matter here because there is a visa type that might have been relatively easy for you to get if you were under 18.

Comment: @Dorothy An 18-year-old is a legal adult in both the US and the UK. Why would the OP's mother's consent be needed? On the other hand, the OP, as an adult, can't use the [Family of Settled Person](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/eligibility) visa to join a parent.

Comment: @Dorothy your "references" link points to a page for travelers *under* 18, but the traveler is *over* 18, so that page is not relevant.

Comment: Was your father born in the UK? I assume you were born in the Commonwealth of Dominica?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert, but as far as I can tell you cannot go live in the UK with your father at this time.

If you were under 18, and your father were able and willing to support you, you could have applied for a [Family of Settled Person](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/eligibility) visa, category "Joining your parents".

You might be able to enter the UK for a short visit without a visa, but you would have to convince the UK authorities that you were planning to leave at the end of the visit. With a parent in the UK, a US visa overstay extending past your 18th birthday, and no job, education plans, or commitments outside the UK, that would be difficult.

Is it practical for you to go to the Commonwealth of Dominica? Do you have any relatives there? Could your father send money to help support you there?

Comment: Admittedly, this is not likely to apply to AŋımɛơųŞıŧყ Dąıყąmơŋɖơ, but it *is* possible for an adult child to qualify for a Family of a Settled Person visa if the adult child needs "long-term care to do everyday personal and household tasks" because of illness or disability.